# Open drawable resource from string

Tags: android

I need to get a resource from a String:

What i do:

```
InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

What i need:

```
InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(getDrawable("image1"));
```

Anyone knows how to implement getDrawable() funcion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `getResources().getIdentifier` for getting drawable id using string name as :

```
int drwableid = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("image1", 
                                         "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());
InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(drwableid);
```